# Is Apple education pricing only for university, not HS, students?

Tags: apple-store

I'm not in university, but I am in high school.

Is this enough to qualify for the educational discounts that Apple offers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staff of **all grade levels**, from kindergarten through post doctoral candidates are now eligible for Education discounts direct from Apple.

Additionally, parents, staff and students at the collegiate level qualify for the EDU discount.

- https://www.apple.com/us-hed/shop/browse/open/salespolicies/edu

## Apple Education Pricing

> Available to current and newly accepted college students and their parents, as well as faculty, staff, and homeschool teachers of all grade levels. <sup>[4](https://www.apple.com/us-hed/shop/browse/open/salespolicies/edu)</sup>

---

In the past, the discount was widely available to K-12 and you can see results below to reflect that past discount.

On the [Apple Store for Eduction](http://www.apple.com/shop/browse/home/findyourschool), you can find your educational institution so you can shop with your discount.  Using "New York, NY" as the city and state and selecting K-12 we see that there used to be an extensive list of schools:

[image: Apple Edu Store]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "of all grade levels" only applies to the "teachers, homeschool teachers, administrators and staff" portion of the education pricing policy.  High school students are not eligible unless they have been accepted to college.

Comment: @dan.  Incorrect.  We bought a Macbook for our HS freshman using this program.

Comment: I've got to agree with Dan. Just because you managed to buy something using the edu pricing scheme doesn't mean you *should* have been allowed to buy it with that pricing scheme. The only students listed in the text on the apple site are "college students" and "parents buying for a college student". The others eligible for the special pricing are "teachers, homeschool teachers, administrators, and staff of all grade levels."

Comment: And if you read the "eligibility" section of that same page you linked to (click 'see terms and conditions'), it clearly says that only students of higher education institutions in the US -- or those accepted to said institutions -- are qualified for the special pricing. Otherwise it's limited to staff.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas  Just for you and Dan, I just went online at the link provided and it allowed me to check out with the discount.   I also called my local Apple store  and they said the discount extends to HS students.  Not sure how much more you guys need.

Comment: @Allan - The legal "small print" on the terms and conditions page unfortunately disagrees with the individual you spoke to on the phone. And when it comes to legalese, especially when the same T&C page lists recourses and talks about audits, I'd rather err on the side of the written legal terms and not a he-said-she-said situation over the phone. Also your being able to check out just means that they are assuming that you're a staff member of the K-12 schools, which is fully allowed to purchase per the terms.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas.  That's a lot of assumption there.  Secondly, (without getting into a legal debate) there are lots of things written into ToCs are the unenforceable because it's impractical or illegal.  Example:  it's illegal to invalidate warranty if you open your device.  it's impractical to exclude a group within a larger group (HS from Edu).  Just because it's written doesn't mean it's binding.

Comment: Hi Allan - Please hit me up in chat if you’re not  amenable to the major edit like the one I made below with the TL;DR that EDu discount used to be much more flexible, but now it’s staff only at K-12 and student+parent+staff at the college level? If you like my edit - consider deleting everything below the - - - line as well unless you feel it’s good to have the context in the accepted answer. I left it in since it helps explain all the old comments. If you’re OK with the new short answer - flag this as other and I’ll delete all comments here too.

Answer (score 7):

In the past, Apple was very casual about handing out educational discounts. This started to change in 2016 and now as of fall 2017 there is a formal verification process that is outsourced to a verification program that checks hardware purchases as well as discounts to services like iTunes Apple Music service discounts for students.

The TL,DR summary of education pricing is:

## Apple Education Pricing

> Available to current and newly accepted college students and their parents, as well as faculty, staff, and homeschool teachers of all grade levels.4

Unless you have been accepted to a college, it is not supposed to be enough.

The [terms and conditions](https://www.apple.com/us-hed/shop/browse/open/salespolicies/edu) page states that the following people are eligible

There is no longer mention of students at the K12 level - only staff at all education levels.

Answer (score 1):

I worked at the Apple store in CT for almost three years and, while you can easily use the Apple Store for Education without being verified no matter WHO you are, it is not using the discount in an honest manner.  If you go to the store, unless the specialist does you a favor, probably in return for you giving him/her a good review on the survey that comes with your receipt, which negates the whole purpose of the feedback you give and the intent of the survey.  Apple believes in positive intent; they don't verify on the web site. This was always maddening to us at the retail level because we repeatedly were told and reminded that it is ONLY FOR COLLEGE STUDENTS (and teachers/staff of ANY GRADE school or homeschool or school board.  So during this summer's promotion where Apple's offering Wireless Beats on top of the discount, you have a choice.  You can order online whether you're a gas station attendant or a breeder of Springer Spaniels and just lie, or you can do the right thing and only take the discount if you qualify for it according to Apple's guidelines.

As for proof in the store, you can bring an acceptance letter if you're in high school and accepted at a university so you can buy a new computer for college, or you can bring a badge, or show that you have a school email.  What you REALLY must bring, though, is your driver's license or learner's permit.  That's the weird part.  We were told it is in case we are audited.  Apparently it is supposed to be a US program for US students and US university so you have to be able to prove you live here.

Answer (score 0):

Step by Step sure fire method to find out -

1. Pick up phone.
2. Dial 1800MYAPPLE (1-800-692-7753)
3. Ask to speak to a customer service rep familiar with the program.
4. "Hello, my name is Zac and I am currently a student at X High School located in Y state. Do I qualify for a student discount?"
5. ???
6. Profit

If you follow my method and are unable to find out and feel comfortable doing so, post your high school name and I will call them to find out for you and report back.

Comment: No thanks, I got it sorted - but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Anyone in the US can get Apple's education pricing. Anyone. Select a school during the checkout. There is no verification process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If your a high school student as long as you sign up and get verified for a UNiDAYS account it will give you a deal to get a macbook with beats included.